# Trying to customize .slick-next & .slick-prev by overriding default properties but my CSS isn't registering. Why? How to fix?

Tags: reactjs, carousel, slick.js

I'm making a carousel for a project, and I'm using Slick. I need the left and right arrows to be inside the picture itself but by default the arrows are to the pictures side. I can that by editing the slick-theme.scss file in the node-modules directly but when I try to have my own custom css file to overwrite the default, it doesn't work.

In slick-theme.scss I just changed the following to get the arrows where I want them:

```
.slick-next {
   right: 10px;
   z-index: 1;
```

And the same for .slick-prev

But I need those changes in a local .scss file to override that. Here's what I'v tried:

```
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss';
import styles from './styles.module.scss';
```

And inside styles.module.css I have

```
.slick-prev {
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
 }

.slick-next {
   right: 10px;
   z-index: 1;
 }
```

I thought that those changes I made in my local css file would be reflected but they're not. When I open up the develop console and inspect the arrow, it doesn't see my customizations at all. Note: There are other customizations in that same CSS file that are working, so the file is hooked up properly - That's not the issue.

Comment: Is your CSS specific enough? Your local changes won't be shown if the SCSS earlier has more specific element selectors. Try adding `!important` to see if they show up then.